# youtube videos audio quality

Tags: audio, youtube

When I watch some video on youtube, sometimes I change the video quality for example from 480p to 720hd by clicking on the bottom right menu:
does this `vq=` parameter also affects the AUDIO quality of the video?

Answer (score 0):

If you watch it with the high quality option (or HD), you will experience the audio in stereo. So it has more of a surround sound feel, or how you would hear your music on your iPod, where certain things are only heard on the left or right. If you watch it in standard quality, then it is basically in mono, where the sound is distributed evenly to both speakers, and audio is slightly degraded to load faster. You can hear the difference if you change between high quality and standard.